# How can I SQL Select header records joined to bill detail lines base on max date in detail line

Tags: sql-server

I need to select claims based on the last date of service in the claim detail lines. I have 2 tables `CLM_HDR` and `CLM_DET`.
Each row returned from the select represents a detail line of a claim plus data from the header of the claim.

`CLM_HDR`

```
|CLM_ID  |PATID |ADMIT_DT  |  
|--------|------|----------|  
|ub100   |2131  |2017-07-29|  
|ub110   |5215  |2017-07-15|
```

`CLM_DET`

```
|CLM_ID  |PATID |LN_ID |DATE_OF_SERVICE|
|--------|------|------|---------------|
|ub100   |2131  |ln01  |2017-07-29     |  
|ub100   |2131  |ln02  |2017-07-30     |  
|ub100   |2131  |ln03  |2017-07-31     |  
|ub100   |2131  |ln04  |2017-08-01     |  
|ub110   |5215  |ln01  |2017-07-15     |  
|ub110   |5215  |ln02  |2017-07-16     |
```

Please forgive the dashes, they are not in the table.

I need to select claims that have a date of service between`'2017-01-01'` and `'2017-01-31'`. If there are any dates of service after `'2017-01-31'` the entire record (`CLM_HDR` and `CLM_DET`) should be excluded.

Here is the last thing I've tried:

```
SELECT c.CLM_ID,
       c.PATID,
       c.ADMIT_DT,
       d.LN_ID,
       d.DATE_OF_SERVICE
FROM   CLM_HDR c
INNER JOIN  CLM_DET d ON  
      c.CLM_ID = d.CLM_ID
WHERE c.ADMIT_DT between ‘2017-07-01’ and ‘2017-07-31’
GROUP BY    c.CLM_ID,
        c.PATID,
        c.ADMIT_DT,
        d.LN_ID,
        d.DATE_OF_SERVICE
HAVING (MAX(d.DATE_OF_SERVICE) <= ‘2017-07-31’)
AND (MIN(d.DATE_OF_SERVICE) > ‘2017-07-01’)
ORDER BY    c.CLM_ID, c.PATID
```

It returns all the lines including the `ub100` claim line with a `DATE_OF_SERVICE = '2017-08-01'` where I was hoping the entire claim would be excluded. I've tried just about everything I could find and even then some. My SQL knowledge is fairly limited. I appreciate any direction/help! Thanks

Comment: if you want any record excluded with date of service not in your range, why not just include it in the where clause?

Comment: I failed to explain that the requirement is that if any line item falls outside of the reporting month, none of the line items should be reported for that month. e.g. a claim consists of 1 CLM_HDR record and multiple CLM_DET records.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to include claims that have events between given dates, but exclude those claims that have events after a certain date you could use something like this:

There are several ways to write this query, and we might change it based on **performance** requirements, but first - please let me know if it satisfies your functional requirements.

```
       SELECT c.CLM_ID,
               c.PATID,
               c.ADMIT_DT,
               d.LN_ID,
               d.DATE_OF_SERVICE
        FROM   CLM_HDR c
        INNER JOIN  CLM_DET d ON  
              c.CLM_ID = d.CLM_ID
        WHERE 
         c.ADMIT_DT between ‘2017-07-01’ and ‘2017-07-31’ and
         c.CLM_ID NOT IN
         (
         SELECT c.CLM_ID
         FROM CLM_DET c
         WHERE c.DATE_OF_SERVICE >  ‘2017-07-31’
         )
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the right direction I think. Of course, being my first question, I over-simplified the data. I think the last where clause should be "WHERE d.DATE_OF_SERVICE > '2017-07-31', correct?

Comment: @Buddaman Yes, you are right. Sorry for the typo, it was pretty late in the evening. I will fix my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated query utilizing a CTE (or without a CTE if you'd like)

```
with cte as(
select
    CLM_ID
from 
    CLM_HDR h
    inner join
    CLM_DET d on d.CLM_ID = h.CLM_ID
group by
    CLM_ID
having
    max(d.DATE_OF_SERVICE) <= '20170131')

select
    h.*
    ,d.*
from 
    CLM_HDR h
    inner join
    CLM_DET d on d.CLM_ID = h.CLM_ID
where
    h.CLM_ID in (select * from cte)
    and d.DATE_OF_SERVICE between '20170101' and '20170131'
```

**INLINE VERSION**

```
select
    h.*
    ,d.*
from 
    CLM_HDR h
    inner join
    CLM_DET d on d.CLM_ID = h.CLM_ID
where
    h.CLM_ID in (select
                    CLM_ID
                from 
                    CLM_HDR h
                    inner join
                    CLM_DET d on d.CLM_ID = h.CLM_ID
                group by
                    CLM_ID
                having
                    max(d.DATE_OF_SERVICE) <= '20170131') 
    and d.DATE_OF_SERVICE between '20170101' and '20170131'
```

Comment: I think that using both what you and ironstone have suggested, I can get to the answer here. Thanks!